# Why does expo-router doesn't work on web?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I am using expo-router in my react native app. When I run my app on iOS or android the routing works as expected but when I open on web using localhost the routing is unmatched. When I press the sitemap some of the components are missing which explains why it can't find the route, the question is - why don't all the components show?

[unmatched route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZnr6.png)
[sitemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXz3o.png)

Routing on web should have worked fine as at worked fine on iOS and android

Comment: sometimes I've noticed some files/components/routes are 'greyed out' and usually means there is no default export from that file

I'm beginning to think that under the hood expo router relies quite a lot on default exports in the files/components you want to use as routes  anyone agree?